# Vue ChatJS redirect on pointer click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am using ***[Vue ChartJS](https://vue-chartjs.org/)*** and I am generating a `Line Chart` and everything works fine.

### What I am trying to do:

I am trying to redirect the user whenever the user click on a pointer.

Kindly check the screenshot[image: screenshot]

For example whenever clicking on the first pointer the user redirect to `invoices/month_of_the_pointer`.

### The Code:

```
chart_data: {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
  datasets: [
    // GENERATED DYNAMICALLY FROM A FUNCTION
  ],
},
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function(label, index, labels) {
          return env.EGP_CURRENCY + label;
        },
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: true
      },
    }],
    xAxes: [ {
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    display: true
  },
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false
},
```

### What I have tried:

I have tried to add `onClick` callback, and it return the click event but not only on the pointers, it return the click even in all the chart

```
onClick: function(evt) {
  console.log(evt);
},
```

Comment: did you try `console.log(evt.target);`?

Comment: Did you try `@click`?

Comment: What exactly you get in `evt` when clicking on pointer?

"it returns the click even in all the chart"

It's an expected behaviour

Comment: As @VasiliyRusin said you get the click event in all the chart not only in the pointer. So I can't detect which pointer I clicked to redirect the user.

Comment: @Deda how? I don't understand where to use `@click`

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to access curent `Chart` instance. I have fond this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/367), in which author states that current instance is saved in `this.$data._chart`.

Then you should call [`getElementsAtEvent`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementsatevente) method of instance, passing an `event` as the first argument.

> Calling `getElementsAtEvent(event)` on your Chart instance passing an
>   argument of an `event`, or jQuery `event`, will return the point elements
>   that are at that the same position of that event. This functionality
>   may be useful for implementing DOM based tooltips, or triggering
>   custom behaviour in your application.

`this.$data._chart.getElementsAtEvent(event);`

Then, implement your custom login, depending on the returned value of that method (if you are using Vue Router: `this.$router.push("/path/to/redirect");`).

Comment: I have tried `this.$data._chart` and logging it to the console in the `mounted()` function and it returned `Chart` instance as you said but I am stuck their.

Comment: @Danny, then bind `@click="clickHandler"` to the chart component in your parent. `clickHandler(event) { this.$data._chart.getElementsAtEvent(event); }`, then apply your custom logic.

Comment: There is also 'getElementAtEvent' ("Element" in singular form) available.